# Kafka Spark Producer Receiver Communication

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am trying to create a basic Kafka producer and receiver just to understand how things work. The code below doesn't yield any errors, but my receiver doesn't seem to be receiving anything. Also, the producer seems to be sending very slowly.

Can anyone tell me why the receiver isn't printing anything, and why the producer is sending so slow?

Here's my producer that I run first:

```
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils
import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.{KafkaProducer,ProducerRecord}

object ProducerTest{


  def extractOptions(properties: Map[String, Any]): Properties = {
    val props = new Properties()
    properties.foreach { case (key, value) => props.put(key, value.toString)     }
    props
  }


  val mandatoryOptions: Map[String, Any] = Map(
    "bootstrap.servers" -> "127.0.0.1:9092",
    "acks" -> "all",
    "batch.size" -> 16384,
    "linger.ms" -> 1,
    "buffer.memory" -> 33554432,
    "key.serializer" ->     "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer",
    "value.serializer" ->     "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")

  val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String]    (extractOptions(mandatoryOptions))

  val TOPIC="test"

  def urlRecall {

    println("Hallo")

    val record = new ProducerRecord(TOPIC, "key", "hallo")
    producer.send(record,null)

    urlRecall

  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    urlRecall

  }

  ;
}
```

The code below shows the receiver that I run in a separate window. It doesn't give any errors, but doesn't print anything either:

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._

object kafkaConsumerTest extends App {

  val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
    "bootstrap.servers" -> "127.0.0.1:9092",
    "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
    "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
    "group.id" -> "1",
    "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
    "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
  )

  val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("NetworkWordCount")
  val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))

  val topics = Array("test")
  val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
    ssc,
    PreferConsistent,
    Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
  )

  stream.print()

  ssc.start()
  ssc.awaitTermination()

}
```

Comment: did you try consuming using `console kafka consumer` just to verify if it receives data from producer to see if producer is working fine ? it may give you an idea if producer is **really** sending something over the wire.

Comment: In attempting your solution I followed the basic instructions on Kafka's website, and insodoing had to start zookeeper and the kafka server itself which solved the problem. I somehow thought that this would happen automatically with the code in my question what was I thinking! If you post your comment (or something to that effect) as an answer I can mark this as aswered? Thanks for your pointer.....

Comment: That's fine, you can just upvote the comment, that is why I added it there. It is not a real answer per say. So let me not try to create one forcefully.